# Converting code written in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, algorithm

I have the following Python code snippet and I am trying to convert this to PHP. This actually generates [Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code).

**Python**:

```
x,n=0,1<<int(sys.argv[1])
while n>x:print bin(n+x^x/2)[3:];x+=1
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $number);
$x=0; $n=1<<$number

while($n > $x) {
    print decbin($n+$x^$x/2);
    x++;
}
```

Now, in the Python code there is a code at 2nd line inside the while loop:

```
bin(n+x^x/2)[3:];
```

I have converted this line to:

```
decbin($n+$x^$x/2);
```

but, what should be this: `[3:]` in PHP? And am I right for as far as I converted?

Comment: It perhaps is http://php.net/substr - Most likely you have not much clue at all what the python code in concrete does? I would start with understanding it first, so it's more easy for you to just look it up in the PHP manual. (Disclaimer: I'm a Python NOOB)

Comment: I have edited my question. This python code generates [Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code).

Comment: So that language construct is for substring access. PHP has strings and string functions, too, they are explained in the PHP manual: http://php.net/string and http://php.net/strings

Comment: Please note the title is misleading. You are not asking about the `while` loop.